# Php/mysql Selecting data from table based on the input provided in a drop down

Tags: php, mysql, dropdown

I am basically trying to select data from the backend mysql database based on the input gathered in a previous drop down. However, I am not able to get this working. Looks like I am missing something, but unable to figure that out!!

Here is the code snippet that I am trying..

```
376               <div class="col-md-4"><label for="doctor">Doctors:</label></div>
377                 <div class="col-md-8">
378                     <select name="doctor" class="form-control" id="doctor" required="required">
379                       <option value="" disabled selected>Select Doctor</option>
380 
381                       <?php display_medis(); ?>
382                     </select>
383                   </div><br/><br/>
384 
385 
386                         <script>
387               document.getElementById('doctor').onchange = function updateFees(e) {
388                       var selection = document.querySelector(`[value=${this.value}]`).getAttribute('data-value');
389                       document.getElementById('docFees').value = selection;
390               };
391             </script>
392 
393 
394                   <div class="col-md-4"><label for="consultancyfees">
395                                 Consultancy Fees
396                               </label></div>
397                               <div class="col-md-8">
398                               <!-- <div id="docFees">Select a doctor</div> -->
399                               <input class="form-control" type="text" name="docFees" id="docFees" readonly="readonly"/>
400                   </div><br><br>
```

Function code

```
function display_medis()
{
 global $con;
 $query = "select med_name,med_id,mrp from med_inv";
 $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
 while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) )
 {
  $med_name = $row['med_name'];
  $mrp = $row['mrp'];
  $med_id=$row['med_id'];
  echo '<option value="' .$med_name. '" data-value="'.$mrp.'" >'.$med_name.'</option>';
  //echo '<option value="' .$med_name. '" data-value="'.$mrp.'" data-spec="'.$med_id.'">'.$med_name.'</option>';
  //echo '<option value="' .$med_name. '" >'.$med_name.'</option>';
  //echo '<option value="' .$mrp. '" >'.$mrp.'</option>';
 }
}
```

Any suggestions.

![Screenshot][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMwjz.png)

Comment: _"based on the input gathered in a previous drop down"_ - and where exactly is that part supposed to be, in what you have shown us? The `display_medis` function only appears to populate the initial select field with options.

Comment: Next time, please do NOT include the line numbers in your code. Thanks

Comment: @CBroe, So basically if you look into the image attached, there is a drop down where i select a value. Based on the value selected, the data-value needs to be populated on the next text box (docFees). However, that is something that I am not able to achieve. Hope, I was able to clarify.

Comment: So you want to do this purely on the client side, using JavaScript? Then your question title is quite a bit misleading.

Comment: And if you want to discuss a client-side problem - then you should show client-side code. No one of us here has your database content available, to exactly reproduce what your `display_medis` function will create. You should rather show us the resulting HTML in a case like this to begin with, the PHP/MySQL part is rather irrelevant here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some syntax problem in your original JS script to process the select drop-down selected value.

Please change

```
<script>
document.getElementById('doctor').onchange = function updateFees(e) {
var selection = document.querySelector(`[value=${this.value}]`).getAttribute('data-value');
document.getElementById('docFees').value = selection;
};
</script>
```

to

```
<script>
document.getElementById('doctor').onchange = function updateFees(e) {
var selection=this.selectedOptions[0].getAttribute('data-value');
document.getElementById('docFees').value = selection;
};
</script>
```

Sandbox link (working):

http://www.createchhk.com/SOanswers/SOtest5Oct2022.html

Comment: Thanks Ken for looking into this. Point noted on the line number for future. I made the changes that you suggested. But still the value is not getting populated on the page.

Comment: You may try the sandbox link (see my revised answer showing the link - tested and it works)

Comment: The sandbox link is working perfectly fine. This is what I intend to achieve. Have you edited the code too. I do not see any change here. I copied and tried. The value is still blank on the page. Looks like there is something that I am missing :(.

Comment: i think you may have other code which interferes with the onchange function? say if u have other HTML element also having id=doctor /docFees ?

Comment: Thanks.....was able to get it working. This helped.

Answer (score 0):

```
function display_medis(){
 global $con;
 $query = "select med_name,med_id,mrp from med_inv";
 $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
 $option = '';
 while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) )
 {
  $med_name = $row['med_name'];
  $mrp = $row['mrp'];
  $med_id=$row['med_id'];
  $option .= '<option value="' .$med_name. '" data-value="'.$mrp.'" >'.$med_name.'</option>';
 }
 echo $option;
}
```

And now your script code should look like this

```
<script>
  $('#doctor').on('change',function(e){
    var selection = $('#doctor option:selected').val();
    $('#docFees').val(selection);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Tumusiime. Was able to get it working.